# Providing array as log entry context

Tags: symfony, logstash, kibana-4

**Solution provided down below...**

I am currently working on a project which required a lot of activity logging that will be available to customer.

I went for an `ELK` stack. Needles to say, I set it all up and it works great.

However, if I do in `Symfony2` something like this:

```
$this->get('logger')
    ->info('Some fabulous message', ['payload' => $payload]);
```

... Logstash creates a set of fields prefixed with `@fields.ctxt_payload` which contain the data. For example:

```
`@fields.ctxt_payload.foo`
`@fields.ctxt_payload.foo.bar`
`@fields.ctxt_payload.foo.bar.meh`
`@fields.ctxt_payload.another`
```

### **The question:**

Is there anything I could do to make `logstash`/`kibana` retain original `json` structure?

Flatten out object won't do the trick as the payload sometime could corry a lot of data.

This is what I tried as well:

```
$this->get('logger')
    ->info('Some fabulous message', ['payload' => json_encode($payload)]);
```

and then in `logstash` configuration:

```
input { 
    redis { 
        queue => "logstash"
        debug => true
    } 
}
filter{
    json {
        source => "payload"
        target => "parsed"
    }
}
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
        host => "localhost" 
        protocol => "http" 
    } 
}
```

But for some reason `logstash` does not create a `parsed` field. :-/

**Any suggestion?** Is this even possible?

## Solution:

Architecturally, I had the following data flow:

- `Monolog` pushes the data via `emran/logstash-bundle` to `redis`
- `logstash` picks that up via `redis` input
- `logstash` parses the fields via `json`
- `logstash` pushes the data to `elastic`

Well, `emran/logstash-bundle` was the culprit. It was formatting the data with `@fields` prefix. To overcome this, I had to change the data flow:

- `Monolog` pushes the data via built-in `gelf` handler
- `logstash` picks that up via `gelf` input
- `logstash` parses the fields via `json`
- `logstash` pushes the data to `elastic`

As soon as I switched to `gelf` format, the following would start working:

```
$this->get('logger')
    ->info('Some fabulous message', ['payload' => $payload]);
```

And the data would get parsed.

Thanks a lot to Alain Collins from comments. I would have spent hours if not days blaming `logstash` if it weren't for him.

Comment: Your first example looks like a bunch of nested fields, which would match a json document.   Query one with curl and look at the output.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks @Alain. I was able to curl that the last message that was sent like in first example and I've got this: http://pastebin.com/Q1r9Lv58.

Comment: All those @ fields means you're on some very old software.  For many reasons, you should consider upgrading.

Comment: Hm, well, I thought I installed the latest :-/ `ElasticSearch 1.4.4`, `logstash 1.4.2` and `Kibana 4`. `Symfony2` is at it's latest as well, but I'm not sure about component that sends the data to `redis`. Thanks for the hint, I'll gladly look into it...

Comment: You are the man! :) You were right! It turns out that the component between `Symfony2` and `Redis` was formatting the data awkwardly and , apparently, `logstash` was not able to parse the `json` properly. Can you please and an answer so I could mark it as correct? :)